# Signal 11 in a prime factorization problem

Tags: c++, memory-management

Apparently I am attempting to access a memory adress that hasn't been allocated. Can someone please tell me where? (The program to prime factorize n given numbers)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sieve(int n){
    int primes[n + 1];
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        primes[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        if(primes[i] == i){
            for(int j = i*i; j <= n; j += i){
                if(primes[j] == j){
                    primes[j] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(n != 1){
        cout << primes[n] << " ";
        n /= primes[n];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie();
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        sieve(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of The Sieve is that you generate the table once and then just look up values in it. Generating it once for every number defeats the purpose. (Also, variable-length arrays are both non-standard and prone to error. Use `std::vector`.)

Comment: This  sounds like a great opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: FYI, you should start your prime number search at 3 and increment by 2.  The number 2 is the only even prime number.  You could "cheat" and create a static array of prime numbers up to 50. :-)

Comment: How do you know that you're hitting an uninitialised address?  What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

This loop is very suspect:

```
while(n != 1){
    cout << primes[n] << " ";
    n /= primes[n];
}
```

How sure are you that n won't become 0? And you haven't initialized primes[0] to anything, so it could be any random value. At that point, n becomes who knows what, and you're off in la-la land.